# Ionic toggle menu doesn't close side menu on android device

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I have an Ionic 4 project and I'm using a side menu. There's a menu button that opens the menu, and in the menu is a list of menu-choices, when selected the menu-choice closes the side menu. This works in a browser, but not on a device. The menu will open, but not close.

My side menu is in my app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu side="start" type="push" contentId="content1">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content class="light-grey">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item (click)="toggleMenu()" [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active-link">Home</ion-item>
          <ion-item (click)="toggleMenu()" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" routerLinkActive="active-link">Dashboard</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="content1" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

Here is a sample of the homepage

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button autoHide="false" menuToggle></ion-menu-button>
          </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>
         Opportunity Forms
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed"  (ionRefresh)="ionRefresh($event)" >
      <ion-refresher-content 
          pulling-icon="arrow-dropdown"
          pulling-text="Pull to refresh"
          refreshing-spinner="circles"
          refreshing-text="Refreshing...">
      </ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>
  <ion-card> 
      <ion-card-content>


      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Here is a screenshot of the app

[image]

Works in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90
Tested and menu does not close on Android 9

Any help is appreciated, hopefully I've provided enough information.

-- Edit (adding app.component.ts) --

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {MenuController} from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private route: Router
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
  toggleMenu() {
    this.menu.toggle(); //Add this method to your button click function
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this. It discusses the issue:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19354

They suggest updating @ionic/angular to 4.11.2. That did not work for everyone but another proposed solution that worked for someone is:

```
<ion-menu-toggle menu="first" autoHide="false">
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using the latest Ionic and 
I tried setting my menuId="first" then using the snippet above and this does not work either.

Comment: Never mind, I had to create a new ionic project and copy over my app folder but updating did help.

Comment: Austin, did updating @ionic/angular to 4.11.2 alone help or was it creating a new ionic project with the latest and greatest of all the applications modules?

Comment: Creating a new project with the latest greatest, then copying over my pages worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

you need to import MenuController and then use that in the button:

the typescript:

```js
...
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss'],
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public menu: MenuController
  ) {}
}
```

the html:

```html
<ion-menu side="end" menuId="first" contentId="main">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item button (click)="this.menu.close()" routerLink="/home">
        <ion-icon name="home-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        Home
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button (click)="this.menu.close()" routerLink="/my-profile">
        <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        My Profile
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please give the following code a try:

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-menu side="start" type="push" contentId="content1">
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="light-grey">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item (click)="toggleMenu()" [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active-link">Home</ion-item>
            <ion-item (click)="toggleMenu()" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" routerLinkActive="active-link">Dashboard</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>
      <ion-router-outlet id="content1" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

You have mixed two possible ways. One way is to add `ion-menu-toggle` in html. Another way is to **add a toggle method** in `app.component.ts` and to add a **click event** in the `app.component.html`. You have already added the **toggle method** in die `app.component.ts`, but you don't have added a **click event** on the **items** in the `app.component.html`..

Comment: This isn't working either. I've remove ion-menu-toggle and added the click events like your sample above. Honestly it's like ionic's menu functions like toggle and close aren't firing. There's no errors in the console and I've tried other functions to fire the close and toggle functions.

Comment: hm.. okay. Have you read about this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-menu-off-menu-click-doesnt-close-menu/139330/5 I think you have, but perhaps it is the right hint for you.

Comment: Yeah, I've read through that already. Honestly I've spent hours looking through forums on this issue. I can use menu.open() to open the menu but close and toggle() fail with no errors. So odd.

Comment: Have you tested it on iOS? Can you create a minimal working project and share it with us? Then I can try it on my device.

Comment: I have not tested it on iOS, as I would have to commit it to my Gitlab server to deploy to iOS and I didn't really want to commit with a know issue.
I'll need a little time, I'll package it up and get you a working project today. Thanks!

Comment: Also having this problem just in one tablet (Samsung Tab A). Its works fine on a phone I use to test(Samsung Galaxy S6)